# The activity in graphical layout is not showing up Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, preview

Here is a picture of my problem http://i49.tinypic.com/f35jds.png

So like in the picture where there is that whole white blank space there's supposed to be a device sort of a thing showing the .xml but in a graphical layout and it's not. Does anyone know how to get this back? I recently updated my SDK and Eclipse and since then it's been gone and I really need it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the new sdk. You can get it back by changing the target version (right top of your picture) to android 3.0 or higher or restarting eclipse. You can set the target to 2.3.3 after getting displaying the layout